# Using Javascript to change background-color back and forth?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome Extension. I have this function here:

```
function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
    var range, sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
}

function highlight(colour) {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        try {
            if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE <= 8 case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}
```

I use it to highlight (background-color to yellow) a piece of selected text. The problem is with de-highlighting it.

I did this:

```
function body() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener(
    "click", 
    function(event){
      highlight('transparent');
    }
  );
}
```

Problem with that is:

1) It requires the text to still be selected, but the click de-selects it, so it only works if you re-select the exact same text, and actually click ON IT.

2) It seems to make the page run much slower, even lock it at times.

What I would love to do is this:

When I click away, anywhere, the text is de-highlighted and de-selected (basically, set highlight to transparent or whatever it was before whenever the text gets de-selected).

What do?

P.S - Javascript only. If you have a way of using jQuery, let me know, but keep in mind I have to use it inside a content.js filed for a Chrome Extension.

Comment: Small comment: It's perfectly acceptable to embed JQuery into a content script. When you do this via the manifest file JQuery is run in a sandboxed mode, meaning it does not conflict with the script on the page itself.

Comment: About your main question, I don't see how you're going to be able to revert highlighting after the text has been unselected. Perhaps there's a way to select all the text on the page and remove all highlights or something similar?

Comment: One other small point: Since this is a Chrome extension you don't need that "IE9 and non-IE" code. :-) The fun thing about writing Chrome extensions is that you don't have to worry about any browser in compatibilities.

Comment: Hei Jude. That's what I was thinking about removing highlights. To remove all highlights from the entire page, since I don't see how I can do that without a selected text. The question is, how do I globally remove all highlights from all the text if there is no selection, regardless whether the text is in a <p> or a <div> or a <span> or whatever. If it has a highlight color, then set it to transparent or remove it. No idea how to do that, been searching for going on five days now.

Answer (score 0):

use can use following code for unhighlighting. this will work fine. :)

```
document.designMode = 'on';
document.execCommand("undo", false, 'span');
document.designMode = 'off';
```

Here "span" is the element which is created by.

```
document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)
```